# Unable to connect Vagrant machine to bridged network

Tags: docker, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I have multiple docker containers running on my host, by default all this containers are reachable by hostname (which is the container name) inside a bridged network called docker0 created automatically by Docker.

In addition to docker containers, I have two VMs created using Vagrant. I want to add this two VMs to dockers so they can communicate with docker containers without port forwarding.

this is my Vagrant config for one VM:

```
  config.vm.define :master1 do |m1|
    m1.vm.hostname = "master1.mycluster"
    # m1.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.0.12"
    m1.vm.network :public_network, bridge:"docker0"
    m1.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
      vb.memory = "4596"
    end
  end
```

this is the output of vagrant up :

```
==> master1: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> master1: Checking if box 'bento/centos-6.7' is up to date...
==> master1: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> master1: Fixed port collision for 22 => 2222. Now on port 2201.
==> master1: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> master1: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    master1: Adapter 1: nat
    master1: Adapter 2: bridged
==> master1: Forwarding ports...
    master1: 22 (guest) => 2201 (host) (adapter 1)
==> master1: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> master1: Booting VM...
==> master1: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    master1: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2201
    master1: SSH username: vagrant
    master1: SSH auth method: private key
    master1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    master1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    master1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    master1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    master1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    master1: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> master1: Machine booted and ready!
==> master1: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> master1: Setting hostname...
==> master1: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

ARPCHECK=no /sbin/ifup eth1 2> /dev/null

Stdout from the command:


Determining IP information for eth1... failed.


Stderr from the command:
```

for information this is ifconfig on my host:

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:68:a8:70:ec  
          inet addr:172.17.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:68ff:fea8:70ec/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4274149 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3733889 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:543633116 (543.6 MB)  TX bytes:2151487889 (2.1 GB)
```

Would you please explain to me what is the problem ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

172.17.0.1 is always classed as an private internal ip address. It would be like hitting `localhost/127.0.0.1` in your VM and expecting to hit the host machine.

It's possible to do what you want to though, [this](https://coderwall.com/p/2rpbba/docker-create-a-bridge-and-shared-network) link walks through it very clearly.